# How to grant privileges on schema in arbitrary PostgreSQL database?

Tags: postgresql, database-schema, privileges, postgresql-15

Is it possible in PostgreSQL to grant all privileges on a schema of a database other than the one I'm currently connected to (and without using the `\c` command to switch first)?

For example, I'm connected as user `postgres` to the database `postgres`. Now I want to grant `someuser` all privileges on schema `public`:

```
GRANT ALL ON SCHEMA public TO someuser;
```

This executes successfully, but applies to schema `public` in the `postgres` database. What I really want is to apply the privileges on schema `public` of the `other` database. Something like this:

```
GRANT ALL ON SCHEMA <other>.public TO someuser;
```

Comment: No, you have to be connected to the database. Postgres does not do cross database references.

Comment: From the manual: `When connecting to the database server, a client must specify the database name in its connection request. It is not possible to access more than one database per connection.` See https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/manage-ag-overview.html

Answer (score 1):

It can be done through dblink extension, like this:

```
select dblink_exec('dbname=other_database user=remote_privileged_user password=password',
                   'grant all on schema public to someuser');
```

If your connected user has privileges in both databases, it's like this

```
select dblink_exec('dbname=other_database',
                   'grant all on schema public to someuser');
```

Which is better because, as pointed out in comments, could be a security breach for a password to be recorded in a transaction log.

Also the password could be retrieved from a file as shown in official docs for [connection string construction](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/libpq-connect.html#LIBPQ-CONNSTRING) since connecting and executing commands to remote PostgreSQL databases (self host or other hosts) has multiple uses.

Be sure that the dblink extension is installed in your local database with

```
select * from pg_extension;
```

If don't create it with

```
create extension dblink;
```

[Official docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/contrib-dblink-exec.html)

Comment: Your password could be written to the postgresql logfiles. Not sure if you want that.  Using psql and just connecting to the correct target database, would be much cleaner.

Comment: @FrankHeikens, that's correct, added another example for that matter.